# unbounded rational function example

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, boundary-value-problem

I assume that if one side of inequality is unbounded, the inequality does not converge. Given J_i = F(X, Y_i)/G(X, Y_i), is there any example of F and G that make J_i unbounded?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Well, sure... f (x,y_i)=x and g (x,y_i)=1.  What actually are you asking.